# Trying to substract each element in a column vector from the first element, and produce the results in a column vector

Tags: matlab, subtraction

i am trying to use a loop to subtract the elements of a column vector from the first element in the same column vector.

so lets say I have `x = [2;3;4;5;6;7;8]` as a column vector.I wish to subtract, `2`, from `3`, then, `2`, from `4`.....and so on until finally, `2` from `8`

the result should be a vector, lets say `y`, where `y` is `[1;2;3;4;5;6]`

my code is

```
x=[2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9];

for k = 1:length(x);
    x(k)=2-x(k);
end
```

clearly does not work.

please help, as fairly new to matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need a loop just try:

```
y = x(2:end) - x(1)
```

but if you want to see how to do it with a loop (pointless in Matlab but useful for learning to code maybe) then it would be like this:

```
for k = 2:length(x)
     y(k-1) = x(k) - 2;
end
```

but again better to replace the `2` in that loop with `x(1)` to make your code more generic

Comment: thats great, thanks so much i eventually arrived at your first suggestions as it was to annoying to let it go. thanks all the same and thanks for the education on for loops.

Answer (score 0):

based on the example you've given the new column vector will be always one element less than the original one.
(forgive me, I don't know if this is the correct matlab syntax but)
try this:

x=[2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9];
newColumnVectorIndex = 1 
for k = 2:length(x); 
newColumnVector(newColumnVectorIndex) = x(k) - x(1) 
newColumnVectorIndex = newColumnVectorIndex+1 
end

hope this helps.